# Intermediate value - then is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this bit of code:

```
  const promises = new Array(20).fill(null).map(v => {
   return c.lockp('foo').then((v => {

     const rand = Math.random()*3000;
     return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,rand)).then(_  => v);
    })
    .then(({key, id}) =>  c.unlockp(key, id)));
  });

  return Promise.all(promises)
  .then(values => {

    console.log('all good');
    process.exit(0);

  });
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).then is not a
>   function
>       at Array.fill.map.v (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/live-mutex/.r2g/tests/smoke-test.js:26:6)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at /home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/live-mutex/.r2g/tests/smoke-test.js:20:43

It should be occurring on 5th line of code in the code snippet above.

Comment: Make sure that `c.lockp('foo')` returns a promise.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.then` is being called on the function with the `v` parameter (which is enclosed in the parentheses right before the `.then`). Put the `.then` *outside* instead, so that it gets called on the promise chain rather than on the callback:

```
const promises = new Array(20).fill(null).map(v => {
  return c.lockp('foo')
    .then(v => {
      const rand = Math.random()*3000;
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,rand)).then(_  => v);
    })
    .then(({key, id}) =>  c.unlockp(key, id));
```

Comment: yeah thanks, weird that syntactically it was fine. my editor didn't complain.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman Also note that you need to remove one `)` after `unlockp`

Comment: Yep, it could *theoretically* be fine, if the parentheses happened to resolve to an object with a `.then` method, which could be called to return *another* function. Pretty weird, but not syntactically forbidden.